# Samba over ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, windows-7, samba

I would like to use an application on a windows 7 machine to edit files on an ubuntu machine that is behind a firewall.

I guess my first question is whether tunneling smb over ssh is a reasonable approach.

If it is then I could use some help setting it up. I used [these instructions](http://www.nikhef.nl/~janjust/CifsOverSSH/VistaLoopback.html). They obviously didn't work for me, but they do summarize what I have done so far.

To simplify the problem I tried tunneling telnet over ssh instead of smb.
In Putty Connection/SSH/Tunnels, I set...

- Source Port: 23
- Destination: 127.0.0.1:23

This works when i telnet to localhost like...

```
telnet localhost
```

or...

```
telnet 127.0.0.1
```

When I say "this works" I mean this connects me to my ubuntu box on the other side of the firewall (the firewall blocks telnet).

It does *not* work when I try to telnet via the loopback adapter like ...

```
telnet 10.255.255.1
```

I initially thought that pointed to a problem with the loopback adapter configuration, but it also does not work when I try to telnet via the physical network adapter like...

```
telnet 192.168.1.7
```

I tried specifying the IP of the loopback adapter in the ssh tunnel source (like below) and I also tried the IP of physical network adapter. In both cases I got the same results as above, telnet via loopback works but nothing else does.

To specify the IP of the loopback adapter, in Putty Connection/SSH/Tunnels, I set...

- Source Port: 10.255.255.1:23
- Destination: 127.0.0.1:23

If any one has any tips on how to troubleshoot this further I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll get much luck tunneling smb over ssh.  Look into something like [OpenVPN](http://www.openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This does seem sorta rube goldberg. I'll take a look at OpenVPN.

Comment: For port forwarding to work you need to forward to localhost port. Windows can't connect to different port. Windows needs the local server to be running to be able to connect to other servers (only in Microsoft this could be considered sane). In short: with Windows it's impossible.